Octez client and node not reporting correct version when built using nix-build
When I build octez executables from source using nix-build, the resulting octez-client and octez-node commands return an unknown version value:
$ octez-node --version
unknown (not-available) (Octez 0.0+dev)

How can I build those so that they report the same version as when building via make?

The reason for this unknown version issue is that nix-build doesn't have access to the git information by default, which is typically used to generate the version string.
To get the correct version reported, you'll need to modify your nix expression to include the git information. The following should be of help:

Make sure you're building from a git clone of the Octez repository, not just a source download.

In your nix expression (probably default.nix or release.nix), you'll want to pass the git revision to the build. You can do this by adding something like:
src = builtins.fetchGit {
  url = ./.;
  rev = "HEAD";
};

This fetches the git info from the current directory.

Then, make sure this git info is passed to the build process. The exact way to do this might depend on how the Octez nix build is set up, but generally, you'd want to ensure the TEZOS_GIT_SHORTREF and TEZOS_GIT_COMMITDATE environment variables are set during the build.

Rebuild with nix-build after making these changes.



Thanks. But I don't find any reference to those environment variables anywhere in the git clone tree (octez-v20.2), and running nix-build after setting them produces executables that report the same "unknown" values.

Not sure what the issue might be again, if you were able to solve it let me know what you did.
